# how to change the background color of Ext.Msg.confirm and Ext.Msg.alert?

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm trying to change the background color of a Ext.Msg.confirm or a Ext.Msg.alert, but I can not change, please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible by changing the `sencha-touch.css` in the `resources/css-debug/sencha-touch.css` file.

Look at this line,

```
/* line 25, ../themes/stylesheets/sencha-touch/default/widgets/_msgbox.scss */
.x-msgbox .x-body {
  background: transparent !important;
}
```

You can add your custom styling here.